# Android - get onActivityResult from outside

Tags: android, android-activity, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement Android's IAB V3 and it asks that i override 'onActivityResult' in my Activity and use it to handle the IAB response.

My problem is that there are cases where i don't have access to the Activity and i need to intercept 'onActivityResult' for my needs. Is it possible to get a callback when an Intent finishes and get all the result data from it ?

Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same problem as you are. Right now I am trying to handle the old IAB v2 intents in a BroadcastReceiver, but this is not a good solution since Google might change the intents it broadcasts  from the GooglePlay app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently solved with a transparent Activity for billing. This Activity implements the 'onActivityResult' in order for IAB v3 to work.

Hope this helps anyone. If you have a better answer please share ...